# addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android

I'm starting in android development and I'm getting that error on the title.

Here is my Contacts.java

```
package us.inevent.toot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Contacts extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ContactListFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class ContactListFragment extends Fragment {

        private ViewGroup listContacts;

        public ContactListFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,
                    container, false);

            listContacts = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listContacts);

            TextView aux = new TextView(getActivity());

            aux.setText("Hello World!");

            listContacts.addView(aux);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Inside the `onCreateView()` method of my `ContactListFragment`, I'm creating a `TextView` with "Hello World" as text.

Then, I'm trying to add that view to my `ViewGroup` listContacts.

Here is my `fragment_contacts.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="us.inevent.toot.Contacts$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/textContact"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_title_text_size" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textContact"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* - you're adding a `TextView` to a `ListView` which isn't allowed through the normal way.

Comment: @Luksprog, how do I add an item to my `ListView`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to set it to your `ListView`. That's not going to work. Try setting it to it's parent. With something like

```
listContacts.getParent().addView(aux);
```

**Edit after comments**

To add an item to your `ListView` you need to add it to whatever list you use to populate your `ListView` and call `setAdapter()` on it or `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`.

You don't add items to your `ListView`. You add items to your `Adapter` and set the `Adapter` on the `ListView`.

I suggest [going through this tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CHgQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidListView%2Farticle.html&ei=3so9U6nVNaj22AX9nYDwCg&usg=AFQjCNEmKxSOQWTEdnIteMT1duTBuc2Xsg&sig2=LE9YKIoMt0RtSrGUUKgdWQ&bvm=bv.64125504,d.b2I)

and reading through the docs thoroughly.

[ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

[Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

**From the docs**

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

Your `ListView` is the `AdapterView` here (it could be a `Spinner` or other such things)

Comment: But I want to add an item to my `ListView`. I cannot accomplish that with your example.

Comment: "But I want to add an item to my ListView"...that is not what you said in your post *at all*.

Comment: how could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout instead of list View.

Answer (score 0):

**Put your List View in Linear Layout and then add any view in your Linear List its not gonna Give the error**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/llist"
tools:context="com.android.parteek.contentprovider.Main2Activity">

  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/serch" />


< ListView   
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android. parteek.contentprovider.Main2Activity">

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also received the issue :

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

I have forgotten to add "false" when I inflate the `.xml`. After adding that it works. My code phrase is as below.

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_format,parent,false);
    }
```