# Populate ExpandableListView from function (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface

I am learning the fundamentals of Kotlin/UI design in android 
I am attempting to dynamically populate a ExpandableListView with data from a DB.
I am currently getting a **addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView** error in my displayInventory function with `elv.addView(txtView)`
I learned from a [related stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848664/addviewview-is-not-supported-in-adapterview) this is because you don't add items to your ListView. You add items to your Adapter and set the Adapter on the ListView.
But the concepts are still a bit foggy given the state of my app, I viewed the recommendation and am still having trouble translating the concepts to kotlin functions and implementing them in my code.

**Question:**
Is it possible to populate a expandableListView dynamically from a function like I am attempting?

If I want to eventually add pictures to my expandableListView, is this an easy change?

Thank you for any help & recommendations.

Here is my CustomExpandableListAdapter class.

```
class CustomExpandableListAdapter internal constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val titleList: List<String>,
    private val dataList: HashMap<String, List<Inventory>>
) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
private lateinit var groupBinding: ListGroupBinding
private lateinit var itemBinding: ListItemBinding

override fun getChild(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int): Any {
    return this.dataList[this.titleList[listPosition]]!![expandedListPosition]
}

override fun getChildId(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int): Long {
    return expandedListPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getChildView(
    listPosition: Int,
    expandedListPosition: Int,
    isLastChild: Boolean,
    view: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup
): View {
    var convertView = view
    val holder: ItemViewHolder
    if (convertView == null) {
        itemBinding = ListItemBinding.inflate(inflater)
        convertView = itemBinding.root
        holder = ItemViewHolder()
        holder.label = itemBinding.expandedListItem
        convertView.tag = holder
    } else {
        holder = convertView.tag as ItemViewHolder
    }
    val expandedListText = getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition) as String
    holder.label!!.text = expandedListText
    return convertView
}

override fun getChildrenCount(listPosition: Int): Int {
    return this.dataList[this.titleList[listPosition]]!!.size
}

override fun getGroup(listPosition: Int): Any {
    return this.titleList[listPosition]
}

override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return this.titleList.size
}

override fun getGroupId(listPosition: Int): Long {
    return listPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getGroupView(
    listPosition: Int,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    view: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup
): View {
    var convertView = view
    val holder: GroupViewHolder
    if (convertView == null) {
        groupBinding = ListGroupBinding.inflate(inflater)
        convertView = groupBinding.root
        holder = GroupViewHolder()
        holder.label = groupBinding.listTitle
        convertView.tag = holder
    } else {
        holder = convertView.tag as GroupViewHolder
    }
    val listTitle = getGroup(listPosition) as String
    holder.label!!.text = listTitle
    return convertView
}

override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun isChildSelectable(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
}

inner class ItemViewHolder {
    internal var label: TextView? = null
}

inner class GroupViewHolder {
    internal var label: TextView? = null
}
}
```

and here is my 'main'

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var adapter: ExpandableListAdapter? = null
private lateinit var binding: ActivityProfileBinding

val database = Firebase.database
val ref = database.getReference("Users")
val mainRef = ref.child(Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid).child("Inventory")
val userInventory : MutableList<Inventory> = ArrayList()
var listData = HashMap<String, List<Inventory>>()


//check hashmap for functionality and next steps to populate expandable list view
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setupExpandableListView()
    setContentView(view)
    val layout : ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.root)

    //profile pic header
    val profilePic : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)
    profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.bermanologylogo)

    //Nav Bar items
    var bottomNavView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)
    bottomNavView.selectedItemId = R.id.profile
    bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { rock ->
        when (rock.itemId) {
            R.id.profile -> {
                val intent =
                    Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
            R.id.feed -> {
                val intent =
                    Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()

            }
            R.id.add_entry -> {
                val intent =
                    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }
        true
    }


    //coroutines to get database contents and display inventory
    GlobalScope.launch {
        var scrollScreen : NestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrolly)

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            getDB()
            listData = sortElements(userInventory) as HashMap<String, List<Inventory>>
            print(userInventory.toString())
            for ((key, value) in listData) {
                println("${key.toString()} = ${value.toString()}")
            }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            displayInventory()
        }
    }

    profilePic.setOnClickListener {

        }


    }


//create and display textviews of current inventory
private fun displayInventory(){

    var elv : ExpandableListView = findViewById(R.id.elv)

    userInventory.forEach { element ->
        var uId = element.Uid.toString()
        var name = element.name.toString()
        var purchDate = element.purchDate.toString()
        var country = element.country.toString()
        var local = element.local.toString()
        var mine = element.mine.toString()
        var weight = element.weight.toString()
        var paid = element.paid.toString()
        var asking = element.asking.toString()
        var description = element.description.toString()
        var dimensions = element.dimensions.toString()
        var filePaths: ArrayList<String> = element.filePaths
        var downloadUrls: ArrayList<String> = element.downloadUrls

        val txtView = TextView(this)
        txtView.text = "Uid: $name\n" +
                "purchase date: $purchDate\n" +
                "country: $country\n" +
                "local: $local\n" +
                "mine: $mine\n" +
                "weight: $weight\n" +
                "paid: $paid\n" +
                "asking: $asking\n" +
                "UId: $uId\n" +
                "dimension: $dimensions\n" +
                "FilePaths:     ${filePaths.toString()}\n" +
                "downloadUrls: ${downloadUrls.toString()}\n"
        txtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        txtView.textSize = 25F

        elv.addView(txtView)
    }
}


/* program populates array with all of users inventory */
private suspend fun getDB() {
    mainRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            val rockTypes = snapshot!!.children


                // This returns the correct child count...
//                println(" Outer count: " + snapshot.children.count().toString())
                rockTypes.forEach { parent ->
                    var specimens = parent.children
//                    val specName = parent.key
//                    val specCount = parent.children.count()
//                    val
//
////                    println("Inner count: " + parent.children.count().toString())
                specimens.forEach { child ->
                    var rock = child.getValue(Inventory::class.java)!!
                    println(rock.name)
                    userInventory.add(rock)
                }
            }
        }


        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
    delay(10000)
}


private fun sortElements(input: List<Inventory>) = input.groupBy { it.name }

private fun setupExpandableListView() {
    val names = ArrayList(listData.keys)
    val expandableListView = binding.elv

    adapter = CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, names, listData)
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter)

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener { groupPosition ->
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            (listData as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition] + " List Expanded.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener { groupPosition ->
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            (listData as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition] + " List Collapsed.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener { parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id ->
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "Clicked: " + (listData as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition] + " -> " + listData[(listData as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition]]!!.get(
                childPosition
            ),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        false
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Custom Adapter view not very necessary here.

You can use simple adapter, customize diffutils, and call **submitList(new list)**

```
class YourDiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ItemUI>() {
override fun areContentsTheSame(
    oldItem: ItemUI,
    newItem: ItemUI
): Boolean {
    return when {
        oldItem is ParentItem && newItem is ParentItem -> {
            oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
        oldItem is ChildItem && newItem is ChildItem -> {
            oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
        else -> {
            false
        }
    }
}

override fun areItemsTheSame(
    oldItem: ItemUI,
    newItem: ItemUI
): Boolean {
    return when {
        oldItem is ParentItem && newItem is ParentItem -> {
            oldItem.isExpanded == newItem.isExpanded
        }
        oldItem is ChildItem && newItem is ChildItem -> {
            oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
        else -> {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

}

In your ParentItem add *isExpanded* field.

Add extensions

```
private fun View.animate(
    @AnimRes animRes: Int,
    duration: Long? = null
) {
    val animation: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animRes)
    if (duration != null) {
        animation.duration = duration
    }
    animation.reset()
    clearAnimation()
    startAnimation(animation)
}
```

inside your Parent view add field for expand control

```
  var isExpanded = false
    set(value) = with(binding) {
        val animArrow = when {
            field == value && value -> {
                R.anim.anim_up
            }
            field == value && !value -> {
                R.anim.anim_down
            }
            value -> {
                R.anim.anim_rotation_up
            }
            else -> {
                R.anim.anim_rotation_down
            }
        }
        arrow.animate(animArrow)
        field = value
    }
```

Update that value in ViewHolder

On click to expandable view **map** your list inside viewModel.
If isExpanded true - add child items. If false - remove child items.
Update your list via function inside adapter:

```
 fun setItems(newList: List<CarouselItemUI>) {
    this.oldList.clear()
    this.oldList.addAll(newList)
    submitList(oldList)
}
```

In my practice, this is the most correct and best way for this task.

Of course, you can try to do it your own way, but my advice:
better read this https://medium.com/@seidalins/delegate-adapters-building-heterogeneous-recyclerviewadapter-877cb7d3c6c0

Comment: I really appreciate the code example. It is probably my lack of android dev knowledge that is leading to my confusion with your answer and applying it in my code.
I was hoping not to have to restructure everything in order for this to work.
Do you have any insight into where my current code is failing and the benefit from your changes